# Is codeigniter 3 compatible with php version 8?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-8

I have to migrate a codeigniter 3 based CRM from PHP version 7.4 to version 8.*. But as I explored about codeigniter 3 compatibility with php 8, I found few answers saying it's not compatible.

But this answers are old (around 1 to 2 year). Two references are:
[Codeigniter Forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-78091.html)
[codeigniter github](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/6006)

So, As reference is old. Is codeigniter 3 currently supports php version 8?

Comment: According to the changelog here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html from version 3.1.12, CI3 has been updated for PHP 8.0 and 8.1 compatibility. However, you may still run into small issues that they missed (e.g. someone posted an issue with the Pagination library here on SO last week that seemed to be caused by PHP 8).

Comment: @Marleen, why don't you post your comment as answer? Just mention the latest release (current version) is now 3.1.13

Comment: Posted as a comment since I haven't used CI3 with php8 myself. Added as an answer now, thanks!

Comment: I'm using a CI 2.3 with PHP 8.0 without any problems.  We did have a lot of code cleanup to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the changelog here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html from version 3.1.12, CI3 has been updated for PHP 8.0 and 8.1 compatibility. The latest release (current version) is now 3.1.13

However, you may still run into small issues that they missed (e.g. someone posted an issue with the Pagination library here on SO last week that seemed to be caused by PHP 8 - [How do I make CI Pagination first page url segment always appear? First page pagination with search query has an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149392/how-do-i-make-ci-pagination-first-page-url-segment-always-appear-first-page-pag) ).

Comment: there are some minor issues due to some deprecated functions, but easy to debug