# Return type of CI_Session_database_driver::open($save_path, $name)

Tags: php

[image]

i got error like this and i tried some ways without success

I tried

i add

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
```

[image]

i use
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2023 11:16:57) (NTS)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and then add all relevant code and potential error messages as text instead.

Comment: What CodeIgniter version are you using? Make sure it supports the PHP version you're using. If it doesn't, upgrade CI to a version that's compatible with PHP 8.2.

Comment: i use CodeIgniter 3.1.11

Comment: You need to upgrade your CI version. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253992/2453432), CI 3.1.12 was released with PHP 8.0 and 8.1 compatibility, so I would guess you should look into upgrading to CI 4 instead.