# Which php version is codeigniter 3.1.11 compatible with?

Tags: php, codeigniter, version-control, upgrade, compatibility

We are using php 5.6 and I am upgrading the php version for codeignitor 3.1.11.

Answer (score 0):

On CI 3.1.11 you can make it all the way up to PHP 7.4.

If you want to get beyond PHP 7.4, you'll need to upgrade your CI to at least the next major version.

CI 3.1.12 is said to be compatible with PHP 8, but word on the street is that there may be some bugs.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74253992/2943403

See also [this CodeIgniter forum thread post and subsequent conversation](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=81171#:%7E:text=%235-,03%2D03%2D2022%2C%2007%3A42%20AM,PHP%208.0%20and%208.1%20compatibility%20along%20with%20other%20changes/bug%2Dfixes.,-Support%20Development%20%E2%80%A2%C2%A0):

> 03-03-2022, 07:42 AM
>
> I know this is an older post, but for those that find this answer later, version 3.1.13 was released today that brings PHP 8.0 and 8.1 compatibility along with other changes/bug-fixes.

Then there are some complaints about buggy business.